# Reducing JPEG file size to 1mb

Tags: jpg

I have a file of JPEG images of our Agents that need to be reduced to 1MB so my boss can add them into his database. How can I reduce their sizes?

Comment: Or if your file is a lot bigger than 1mb then reduce the image pixel size.

Comment: You can also losslessly optimise images with tools like ImageOptim (mac only), fileOptimizer, mozJPEG, Trimage ...

Answer (score 1):

open jpeg images in to photoshop and press ctrl + alt + Shift + S to save for web
and reduse image quality more than 60 to 80 percent. you see attach jpg file [image]